# Не работает свойство SelectedItem для пользовательского элемента управления

Tags: wpf, dependencyproperty

Имеется пользовательский элемент управления `UCComboBox` который является "оберткой" для обычного выпадающего списка (кобмобокса). Код:

```
<DockPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LabelText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:UCComboBox}}" Margin="5"/>
    <ComboBox
        Margin="5"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:UCComboBox}}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedParticipant.CaseStatusType}"
             
    />
    <!--SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:UCComboBox}}"-->
</DockPanel>
```

Когда я явно определяю свойство SelectedItem для комбобокса, как в вышеприведенном примере, то элемент управления работает нормально. Когда же я пытаюсь сделать его переопределяемым через свойство зависимостей, привязка к выбранному элементу перестает работать, хотя ошибки привязки XAML отсутствуют. Код:

```
<DockPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding LabelText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:UCComboBox}}" Margin="5"/>
    <ComboBox
        Margin="5"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:UCComboBox}}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:UCComboBox}}"  
    />
</DockPanel>
```

Свойства зависимостей:

```
public partial class UCComboBox : UserControl
{
    public UCComboBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }



    public string LabelText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LabelTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelTextProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for LabelText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("LabelText", typeof(string), typeof(UCComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));



    public object ItemsSource
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ItemsSource.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(object), typeof(UCComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));



    public object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedItemProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedItem.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(object), typeof(UCComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Пример использования в стороннем коде:

```
<local:UCComboBox
    LabelText="Процессуальный статус: "
    ItemsSource="{Binding CaseStatusList}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedParticipant.CaseStatusType}"
    IsEnabled="{Binding IsEditEnabled}"
/>
```

Как я должен исправить свойство `SelectedItem` во втором примере, чтобы свойство было привязано успешно?

UPD: Я думал, что причина  возможно в том, что собственное свойство выпадающего списка `SelectedItem` названо так же как и свойство зависимости на которое оно ссылается т.е.: `SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:UCComboBox}}"` Но после того, как я добавил "1" в название свойства зависимости и обновил само свойство зависимости и привязку, ничего не изменилось.

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, проблема была в том, что привязка не была двусторонней по умолчанию. Для того,чтобы привязка стала двусторонней в свойство зависимости нужно было передать специальный объект `FrameworkPropertyMetadata` c указанием на двустороннюю привязку следующим образом:

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItem1Property =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem1", typeof(object), typeof(UCComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```